# Format discord.py joined_at

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to get the ugly discord.py method "joined_at" from discord.Member, which looks something like this:

```
member.created_at 
=> 2016-08-31 23:49:10.834000
```

to something like:

```
Wednesday, August 31st 2016 @ 11:49:10 pm
```

I dont want to parse it all myself since it would destroy my codes prettyness. Is there any cool library I can use?

Answer (score 3):

`member.created_at` returns a DateTime object, which has a `strftime` method used for formatting.

```
>>> member.created_at.strftime("%A, %B %d %Y @ %H:%M:%S %p")
Wednesday, August 31 2016 @ 11:49:10 PM
```

The python docs has a [chart of templates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).